# Reactjs setState not being updated immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

I have a function where I'm trying to get an array of emails and checking if it is a valid email:

```
handleValidEmail = (isValid, index, emailValue) => {
  // checks if empty state in optional fields.
  const { emailValueList, isValidEmailArray, isValidEmail } = this.state;

  // need to make copy, to treat the array as immutable
  const newEmailValueList = [...emailValueList];
  newEmailValueList[index] = emailValue;

  const newIsValidEmailArray = [...isValidEmailArray];
  newIsValidEmailArray[index] = isValid;

  this.setState({
    emailValueList: newEmailValueList,
    isValidEmailArray: newIsValidEmailArray,
  }, () => {
    console.log(emailValueList, isValidEmailArray);
    console.log('before', isValidEmail);

    if (every(isValidEmailArray, Boolean)) {
      this.setState({ isValidEmail: isValid });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isValidEmail: false });
    }
    console.log('isvalidEmail', isValidEmail);
  });
}
```

So I did some digging, and I know that if you do a callback to your setState, it should work. However, I'm not getting mine to work.

So when I'm typing in the input field: "test@gmail.co", the console logs:

`console.log(emailValueList, isValidEmailArray);` = `["test@gmail.c"], [false]`

`console.log('before', isValidEmail);` = `before false`

`console.log('isvalidEmail', isValidEmail);` = `isvalidEmail false`

When I type the last letter, "m", to make it test@gmail.com

`console.log(emailValueList, isValidEmailArray);` = `["test@gmail.co"], [true]`

`console.log('before', isValidEmail);` = `before false`

`console.log('isvalidEmail', isValidEmail);` = `isvalidEmail false`

Then when I add another letter at the end:

`console.log(emailValueList, isValidEmailArray);` = `["test@gmail.com"], [true]`

`console.log('before', isValidEmail);` = `before true`

`console.log('isvalidEmail', isValidEmail);` = `isvalidEmail true`

---

I'm trying to get isValidEmail to be true when it hits the first true at `testing@gmail.co`

Why am I not getting this result?

Comment: can you include html file as well?

Comment: You are logging `isValidEmail` which is not a current `state` value, it is the value you set earlier in the `handleValidEmail` function (`const { ..., isValidEmail } = ...`). That variable's value is not going to change when you change your state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this  `if (every(isValidEmailArray, Boolean)) {`

to this:  `if (every(newIsValidEmailArray, Boolean)) {`

You are still referencing the old state.

---

This line will still be false unless you put it inside another callback from `setState`: `console.log('isvalidEmail', isValidEmail);`

The call to setState is not 'instant':
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate